# CSS Variables - Multiple fallbacks not working

Tags: css, css-variables

According to MDN, the `var` function accepts multiple fallbacks. But I am unable to get them to work.

I tried the following code on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. The `background-color` for `.demo3` is transparent on all the above browsers.

Is it an error with the code, or is it because the browsers have not implemented variable fallback?

```css
:root {
  --my-var: red;
}

.demo1 {
  background-color: var(--my-var);
}

.demo2 {
  background-color: var(--my-background, pink);
}

.demo3 {
  background-color: var(--my-background, --my-var, pink);
}
```

```html
<div class="demo1">No fallback</div>

<div class="demo2">Single fallback</div>

<div class="demo3">Multiple fallbacks</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For multiple fallbacks try: `background-color: var(--my-background, var(--my-var, pink));`